# detecting whether GPUs are accessible before running nvidia-smi during boot to create dev files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, kernel

In the past, I've successfully configured Ubuntu systems containing NVIDIA GPUs to launch `nvidia-smi` in the background from within `/etc/rc.local` during the system boot to create the requisite `/dev/nvidia*` files. After recently trying out NVIDIA's 346.46 drivers on Ubuntu 14.04 with CUDA 6.5-19 and Linux kernel 3.13.0-48, I noticed that `nvidia-smi` would hang indefinitely (and never create any `/dev/nvidia*` files) during bootup. I was able to work around this by inserting a delay (i.e., `sleep 30`) in `/etc/rc.local` immediately before launching `nvidia-smi`. Is there some way to check whether the GPUs are somehow "accessible" (for lack of a better word) before starting `nvidia-smi`?

I should add that the problem only seems to affect Tesla GPUs (Fermi generation); I haven't had to add any delays to `/etc/rc.local` on systems with GeForce (Fermi) GPUs.

Comment: Out of curiosity, [nvidia-smi hangs indefinitely: what could be the issue?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/255658/16704)